# batch/powershell to backup wlan profiles - need elevated rights (not admin!)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, backup, profile, wifi

Basically, I want to backup WLAN profiles of my users via batch or PowerShell. This command is working pretty good :

```
netsh wlan export profile key=clear folder="%appdata%\wlan-profiles"
```

I need `key=clear` so i can import those profile independently of Win7 / Win8 / Win10.

Here is the problem: the command shell needs to be started elevated (as normal user (not admin!)) because otherwise the password will be exported as hash and not in plaintext. If password is stored as hash it is not possible to import it on another system.

Is there any way to get a batch or PowerShell script into elevated mode without typing password? **OR** Is there another way to export WLAN profiles in plaintext?

I thought about a scheduled task, but if you want to give parameter `/RL HIGHEST` (Run with highest privileges) then you need to run this command elevated as well.

Do some have any idea or workaround how to do that?

It needs to be working as normal user and should be compatible from Win7 to Win10.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by elevated rights, but not admin. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: What's wrong with the multiple existing solutions: [\[batch-file\] elevate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+elevate)?

Comment: ok, i try to explain: you're a normal user (without admin rights), if you run the command above in a nromal cmd the wlan password will be stored encrypted. if you start the cmd elevated (Stg+Shift) with normal user account then it will be stored in plaintext.

Comment: And what's wrong with the existing solutions that, as far as I can see, solve the problem? I mean have you tried those autoelevation batch files?

Comment: at all solutions i found uac pops up and you need to type your password. I'm looking for a solution without entering your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:

i deploy a installation which installs a scheduled task (task runs as SYSTEM), it runs daily a powershell script if a new user has logged on, for every user (with exclude-list for special admin accounts) a userspecified scheduled task will be created and imported.

In your deployment system or logonscript you can trigger the user-scheduled-task (with highest privvileges) which export all profiles with password in plaintext (to %appdata%_wlan).

it works great and is compatible between Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10.

if anyone need more details, just ask.

powershell script:

```
if(Test-Path "c:\temp\wlan\user.ini"){
    $userliste=get-content "C:\temp\wlan\user.ini"
    $userlisteneu=gci -Path c:\users -Exclude *admin*, *streaming*, *public*, *autologon* , *_* -name
    foreach($user in $userlisteneu){
        if (-not($pruefung=$userliste -match $user)){
            $filename="c:\temp\wlan\WLAN-Backup-$user.xml"
            copy "c:\temp\wlan\WLAN-Backup.xml" $filename
            (Get-Content  $filename) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'Domain\\username',"$env:userdomain\$user"} | set-content $filename  
            cmd /c schtasks /Create /XML $filename /TN WLAN-Backup-$user
            $user | Out-File "C:\temp\wlan\user.ini" -Append
        }
    }
 } else { 
 gci -Path c:\users -Exclude *admin*, *streaming*, *public*, *autologon* , *_* -name | Out-File "C:\temp\wlan\user.ini" -Append
 $userliste=get-content "C:\temp\wlan\user.ini"
 foreach($user in $userliste){
        $filename="c:\temp\wlan\WLAN-Backup-$user.xml"
        copy "c:\temp\wlan\WLAN-Backup.xml" $filename
        (Get-Content  $filename) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'Domain\\username',"$env:userdomain\$user"} | set-content $filename       
        cmd /c schtasks /Create /XML $filename /TN WLAN-Backup-$user
    }
 }
```

command for export

```
%System%\schtasks.exe /Run /TN "WLAN-Backup-%username%"
```

command for import

```
%System%\cmd.exe /c forfiles /p "%appdata%\_wlan" /m *.xml /c "cmd /c netsh wlan add profile filename=@path"
```